# golang convert byte array containing unicode

Tags: go

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Value json.RawMessage `json:"value"`
}

var resp *http.Response

if resp, err = http.DefaultClient.Do(req); err == nil {
    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        var buffer []byte
        if buffer, err = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body); err == nil {

            mystruct = &MyStruct{}
            err = json.Unmarshal(buffer, mystruct)

        }
    }
}

fmt.Println(string(mystruct.Value))
```

it produces something like:

```
   \u003Chead>\n  \u003C/head>\n  \u003Cbody>
```

Doc at: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

says:
When unmarshaling quoted strings, invalid UTF-8 or invalid UTF-16 surrogate pairs are not treated as an error. Instead, they are replaced by the Unicode replacement character U+FFFD.

I kinda think this is what is going on.  I just can't see the answer as my experience with go is minimal and I'm tired.

Comment: Please provide sample code that demonstrates the output you see and your attempt to correct the unexpected behavior.

Comment: can you show exactly what is in your []byte slice? The literal value `\u003C` should be `<` since go always assumes utf-8.

Comment: I edited the post a little.  Hopefully that provides more of a context.  thx

Comment: Why are you using `json.RawMessage` there? If a json encoder encoded message, presumably you want a json decoder to decode it.

Comment: because, the value is a generic value.  It can be anything.  So, the question is: how do I convert the unicode contained within a byte array to the character equivalent?

Comment: a `json.RawMessage` hasn't been unmarshaled. You either need to unmarshal it into a string([example](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage)), or unescape the unicode yourself.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to convert escaped unicode characters in [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) into just valid UTF8 characters without unmarshalling it. (I had to deal with the issue since my primary language is Korean.)

You can use the [`strconv.Quote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote) and [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) to do the conversion.

```
func _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(_jsonRaw json.RawMessage) (json.RawMessage, error) {
    str, err := strconv.Unquote(strings.Replace(strconv.Quote(string(_jsonRaw)), `\\u`, `\u`, -1))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(str), nil
}

func main() {
    // Both are valid JSON.
    var jsonRawEscaped json.RawMessage   // json raw with escaped unicode chars
    var jsonRawUnescaped json.RawMessage // json raw with unescaped unicode chars

    // '\u263a' == '☺'
    jsonRawEscaped = []byte(`{"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}`) // "\\u263a"
    jsonRawUnescaped, _ = _UnescapeUnicodeCharactersInJSON(jsonRawEscaped)                        // "☺"

    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawEscaped))   // {"HelloWorld": "\uC548\uB155, \uC138\uC0C1(\u4E16\u4E0A). \u263a"}
    fmt.Println(string(jsonRawUnescaped)) // {"HelloWorld": "안녕, 세상(世上). ☺"}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pUsrzrrcDG-

Hope this helps :D

Comment: This helped me a bunch!  I was struggling with DecodeRuneInString when retrieving data from a db inserted by php.  But this did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You decided to use `json.RawMessage` to prevent parsing of the value with key `value` in your json message.

The string literal `"\u003chtml\u003e"` is a valid json representation of `"<html>"`.

Since you told `json.Unmarshal` not to parse this part, it does not parse it and returns it to you as-is.

If you want to have it parsed into an UTF-8 string, then change the definition of `MyStruct` to:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```